# Get inner xml from lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following string which is part of an bigger XML Document:

```
content = '<odvNameElem stopID="9001002"><itdMapItemList/>Rathaus</odvNameElem>'
```

And I want to access `Rathaus`. My current approach is to parse it with lxml and trying to access the text of the element *'odvNameElem'*:

```
from lxml import etree
content = '<odvNameElem stopID="9001002"><itdMapItemList/>Rathaus</odvNameElem>'
root = etree.fromstring(content)
print(root.text)
```

This however results in None. What am I doing wrong?

`etree.__version__ = '4.2.5'`

I am not sure why the following works:
`root.xpath("string()")` but `root.xpath("//text()")` only returns an empty list. Can somebody please explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Rathaus" string is the value of the `tail` property of the `itdMapItemList` element. Examples:

```
root.xpath("itdMapItemList")[0].tail
root.find("itdMapItemList").tail
```

See https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text.

---

`root.xpath("string()")` returns the concatenation of the string values of the root node and its descendants, which indeed is "Rathaus" in this case.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-string.

---

`root.xpath("//test")` does not make sense (there is no `test` element). Did you mean `root.xpath("//text()")`?

`root.xpath("//text()")` returns a list of all text nodes, which in this case is `['Rathaus']`.

If the input XML is changed to

```
<odvNameElem stopID="9001002">ABC<itdMapItemList/>Rathaus</odvNameElem>
```

then the result is `['ABC', 'Rathaus']`

Comment: thank you for the detailed and helpfull explanation. And yes I indeed meant `root.xpath('//text()')`